# Registry key for Install update and hotfix information on windows 7

Tags: winapi, windows-7, registry, windbg

I am working on windows 7 support. In my application I want to gather installed updates and patches. Currently I am gathering it from **`WIn32_QuickFixEngineering`**. But it is not giving information for **`InstalledSDate`** , **`Description`**.

I need to get this either from registry or API (C++ application). In other operating system like XP, 2k3 registry keys are-
**`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Hotfix`**
**`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates`**

But these are not present on windows 7.

Can any one give thought on this..

Answer (score 2):

I was also trying to figure out where the registry key for "Hotfix" had moved to.

I am setting up a debug symbol server on Windows 7.  While I was following instructions from the book [Debugging Applications for Microsoft ... Windows (by John Robbins)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615365), I was getting the error "Unable to enumerate the hot fix key" from a piece of vbscript code that Mr. Robbins recommends.

I realized that the vbs code is looking for the reg key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\HotFix, which is not present on Windows 7.

While searching for a substitute key (or any other alternative), I found some helpful information here: [http://forums.cnet.com/5208-12546_102-0.html?threadID=327588](http://forums.cnet.com/5208-12546_102-0.html?threadID=327588#2965033)

The command shown on that cnet forum was a viable substitute in my case:

```
wmic qfe list full
```

shown at the cmd.exe prompt:

```
C:\Users\All Users>wmic qfe list full
```

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387099(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your issue:  InstallOn properties for QFEs are sometimes stored as 64-bit, hexdecimal timestamps.  To use this as a date:
Check first whether it is a hexadecimal value.  If not, it is likely a regular date value.
Then, (in C#) use this to convert it to a DateTime: 
`DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc( Int64.Parse(<InstallOn>, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));`

Answer (score 1):

try looking here:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages]
```