# Identifying installed updates in win vista and win 7?

Tags: c++, windows-7

In winXP, reading the registry entries at location
**SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Hotfix**
would give me a list of all installed updates to my windows system.

I am guessing this practise has been discountinued since windows 7 (may be vista too). So how do I now generate a list of all installed updates? Have they changed the name of the resgistry location? or have they introduced some new method to identify this?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question:

[Registry key for Install update and hotfix information on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742242/registry-key-for-install-update-and-hotfix-information-on-windows-7)

[Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387099%28VS.85%29.aspx) will help if you need to do it from code.